# disabling journal vs data=writeback in ext4 file system

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ext2, journaling

What is the difference between disabling journal on ext4 file system using:

```
tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda1
```

and using `data=writeback` when mounting? I thought `ext4 - journal = ext2`. means when we remove journal from a ext4 file system, it is automatically converted to ext2(thus we can not benefit from other ext4 features)

Comment: ext3 minus Journaling equals ext2, but I have never heard that applies to ext4. Are you sure about that one?

Comment: To disable it you can `mount -o norecovery ...` (or `noload`). This means: "mount without journalling"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two are in no way equivalent. Disabling the journal does exactly that: turns journaling off. Setting the journal mode to writeback, on the other hand, turns off certain guarantees about file data while assuring metadata consistency through journaling.

The data=writeback option in `man(8) mount` says:

> Data ordering is not preserved - data may be written into the main
>   filesystem after its metadata has been committed to the journal. This is
>   rumoured to be the highest- throughput option. It guarantees internal
>   filesystem integrity, however it can allow old data to appear in files
>   after a crash and journal recovery.

Setting data=writeback may make sense in some circumstances when throughput is more important than file contents. Journaling only the metadata is a compromise that many filesystems make, but don't disable the journal entirely unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Does completely disabling journal makes throughput high like `data=writeback`?